# Cambio de dominio en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dominio

hace poco que tengo una cuenta en wordpress.com para un trabajo de un cliente. Dicho cliente se compro un dominio tpaf.org, ahora necesito que mi página salga por la direccion www.tipaf.org y no por la de tipafdot.wordpress.com Ya cambie mi dominio por defecto por el nuevo comprado pero me sale que el servicio es inutilizado, creo que tengo que hacerles algunos cambios mas pero no tengo mucho conocimiento de esto, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que tienes que hacer es que con el proveedor del dominio tienes que configurarlo para que sea una "redirección". Osea, que cuando entren a tipaf.org se redireccione a tipafdot.wordpress.com, y existen dos modos de redirección, uno en que se cambia la dirección del url por la original (tipafdot.wordpress.com) y otro donde se utiliza la dirección del dominio tipaf.org... los nombres y en donde se hace exactamente varía de proveedor a proveedor , depende de si lo compraste con godaddy.com, google, akky o algún otro proveedor